# blackberry webworks compile error

Tags: compiler-errors, blackberry-webworks

I keep encountering an error when I compile my app for blackberry. I'm tried using Ripple and SDK compiler, but I keep running into the same problem. [image]

As you can see, I get an error, but no associated error message, just ERROR. The .bar file is still created, but the app doesn't initialize in the simulator. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!